# Metadata per item in a nodequeue

Tags: 7

An item in a *nodequeue* is a reference to a nid. In some cases you want to add some metadata to this queue item, for example an alternative title or description that is better suited in a specific listing.

One way of doing this is to create a *"nodequeue item"* content type that has a *nodereference* to the actual node. Although this would solve the problem, it wouldn't be the best user experience when administering.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you be specific on the problems with using the _nodequeue item_ approach?

Comment: It requires the user to first create a nodequeue item node and then to return to the nodequeue list page for each item to be added. It would be much better if the user could stay on the nodequeue admin page during the whole list editing instead of having to navigate all over the admin.

Comment: I've not used nodequeue so I could be wrong, but it seems to me that the nodequeue item approach conceptually fits as a solution to the problem. I'd say that you're left with a navigation problem (how do I create a user-friendly workflow while using nodequeue items?). For that problem I think you could alter the nodequeue form to have a _create nodequeue item_ link with the query set to `destination=the/nodequeue/url`. I think you could also use panels to avoid any custom coding.